# How to input array as a parameter in method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm supposed to print a table of array values against their key values. However I receive `'.class' expected`. But I don't know what is wrong with the code. Please help!

```
class createTable {
    public static void main (String args []){
        int array[] = {2,13,15,67,87,34,66,23,11,93};
        printTable (array[]);
    }

    static void printTable (int[] array){
        System.out.println ("Key\tValue");
        for (int key = 0; key < array.length; key++){
            System.out.println (key + "\t" + array [key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `printTable(array);` without `[]` in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you write 
`int array[] = {...};` 
is the same as writing 
`int[] array = {...}`

You are telling the JVM that you are creating an object of type `int[]` (array of int) with reference name `array`. When you want to pass the array as a method parameter you have to write the reference name between brackets.

```
class createTable {
    public static void main (String args []){
        int array[] = {2,13,15,67,87,34,66,23,11,93};
        printTable (array);
    }

    static void printTable (int[] array){
        System.out.println ("Key\tValue");
        for (int key = 0; key < array.length; key++){
            System.out.println (key + "\t" + array [key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `[]` from your argument when calling printTable.

```
printTable (array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove brackets when sending to methods as a parameter. Only with param name also.

So code will be like this:

```
class createTable {
    public static void main (String args []){
        int array[] = {2,13,15,67,87,34,66,23,11,93};
        printTable (array);
    }

    static void printTable (int[] array){
        System.out.println ("Key\tValue");
        for (int key = 0; key < array.length; key++){
            System.out.println (key + "\t" + array [key]);
        }
    }
}
```